# Tabbed View of multipe HTML files in a single HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 HTML files. Now I would like to create a HTML file with three tabs. I am able to create tabs but I am not able to relate each tab with each HTML file so that when I click on a tab, I want content of one HTML file to be shown.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
function includeHTML() {
  var z, i, elmnt, file, xhttp;
  /*loop through a collection of all HTML elements:*/
  z = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
    elmnt = z[i];
    /*search for elements with a certain atrribute:*/
    file = elmnt.getAttribute("w3-include-html");
    if (file) {
      /*make an HTTP request using the attribute value as the file name:*/
      xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4) {
          if (this.status == 200) {elmnt.innerHTML = this.responseText;}
          if (this.status == 404) {elmnt.innerHTML = "Page not found.";}
          /*remove the attribute, and call this function once more:*/
          elmnt.removeAttribute("w3-include-html");
          includeHTML();
        }
      }      
      xhttp.open("GET", file, true);
      xhttp.send();
      /*exit the function:*/
      return;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<body>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>

    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <h3>London</h3>
<div w3-include-html="contact.html"></div> 
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
     <h3>Paris</h3>
<div w3-include-html="contact1.html"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <h3>Tokyo</h3>
<div w3-include-html="contact2.html"></div>
    </div>
  </div> 

<script>
includeHTML();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

this full source for include html page inside multiple html pages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is possible to do that in HTML alone, the only way I can think of is changing pages on tab click and setting active class to control the show and hide of the tabs / active state.

The other way is to integrate the content from those 3 pages into 1 page and use show/hide with some JQuery or CSS3.

More information is always helpful.

Comment: Please check this out...https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_full_page_tabs.asp It shows the same on how to do so but the div elements are present in the same html. How do I refer the div elements present on another HTML.

Comment: Its not possible with only HTML, you got to put content into one page like the example you gave, or like I said put links to the other pages and change pages, like a navigation and check https://codepen.io for example and type "tabs" you have million examples. As much as I can understand you.

Comment: I actually have huge html files with datatables and all..So I can't include them in single html file. For navigation, you mention "change pages" . Do you mean the entire page gets reloaded instead of single tab content? I'm a newbie to this. Please don't mind